# python-magic on GCP App Engine - failing to deploy

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, python-magic

I am working on Python app that will be deployed to GCP App Engine.
I tried to use `python-magic` functionality.
I've added `import magic` to my code and `python-magic` to the `requirements.txt` file.
But when I try to deploy code to App Engine it fails with the following error:

```
[2020-02-03 15:35:23 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import magic
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic.py", line 181, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
[2020-02-03 15:35:23 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
[2020-02-03 15:35:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-02-03 15:35:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What I am missing to setup to make this work?

---

EDIT: sharing minimal setup to reproduce this error

main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import base64
import magic

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from flask import Flask, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/parse', methods=['POST'])
def parse():

    try:
        #input should be a b64 encoded byte string
        input = request.get_json()['input']
    except Exception as e:
        abort(400, 'An error occured while reading in parameters: {}'.format(str(e)))

    decoded_input_data = base64.decodebytes(input)
    mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
    file_ext = mime.from_buffer(decoded_input_data)

    returnData = {}
    returnData['Status'] = 200
    returnData['file_ext'] = file_ext

    return json.dumps(returnData), 200

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def error(e):
    logging.exception(str(e))
    return json.dumps({'Status': e.code,
                       'Message': e.description}), e.code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
google-cloud-vision==0.38.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.11.2
google-cloud-storage==1.15.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
protobuf==3.6.0
python-magic==0.4.15
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
service: myservicename
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 240 --limit-request-line 0

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) library you can follow the next procedure:

***App Engine Standard***

1. Use the [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create an isolated Python environment in a directory external to your project and activate it with:

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

2. Install the [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library with pip by running:

```
pip install python-magic
```

3. Add the library to your requirements.txt file. For example, if you are running the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) from the Official documentation your requirements.txt file should look like this:

```
Flask==1.1.1
python-magic==0.4.15
```

4. Make the import of the library on the relevant module of your application's code. For example, if you are running the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) from the Official documentation the relevant section of your main.py file should look like this:

```
...
# [START gae_python37_app]
from flask import Flask
import magic

# If `entrypoint` is not defined in app.yaml, App Engine will look for an app
# called `app` in `main.py`.
app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

***App Engine Flexible***
The libmagic C library is not pre-installed on flex environment ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#using_c_libraries_with_python) is the list of the installed libraries). You'll therefore need to create a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

Changing your app.yaml to the following:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

And adding the corresponding Dockerfile to your project's directory. For example:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libmagic-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "-b", ":8080", "--timeout", "300"]
```

should suffice to deploy the application successfully.

Notice that the Dockerfile simply installs the libmagic C library, afterwards installs your requirements.txt and finally runs gunicorn on the port required for App Engine. But feel free to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I have done exactly this steps and I am receiving this error.

Comment: Notice that I didn't add the whole code of the main.py of the Quickstart. Just the section that imports the library. Would you mind sharing a minimum, reproducible, example of your code (including app.yaml, requirements.txt and relevant modules where you use the library)?

Comment: I have edited the question with whole minimal setup to reproduce this error

Comment: I edited the file an include a section for App Engine Flexible. As my first answer was using App Engine Standard.